# ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED when running a node app on a server, runs fine locally

Tags: node.js, fabricjs, sveltekit

The `canvas.node` module should be related to fabric.js. The project runs fine locally, it even runs when I try to navigate to the page that has the fabric component. However when I refresh the same page, it crashes with the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error loading shared library /workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: Exec format error
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

The project is running on SvelteKit. I'm using Docker to deploy and the project is being built in the image:

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --platform=linuxmusl --arch=x64 sharp
RUN npm run build
```